# Performance of OpenSAML marshaller and unmarshaller

Tags: java, performance, opensaml

We are using `opensaml` libraries version 3.3.0 and seeing that marshalling takes 25% of the time of the request that comes to my server endpoint for processing. Especially this call `AbstractXMLObjectMarshaller.marshall`, similarly `Signer.signObject` takes around 7% of the time. Is there any way to improve this performance? I am sure `opensaml` library will have some kind of benchmarking.

Few things I have tried for this

1. Using `ParserPool` instead of `DocumentBuilderFactory`
2. Making sure all builder factories and `marshallerFactory` is initialized once
3. Use of `prettyPrintXML` from `SerializedSupport` instead of `nodeToString`.

Comment: What is your operating system? If Linux, what's the result of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz - It is Windows